# C program string mess

Tags: c, string

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
if((string[i] >= 65 && string[i] <= 90) || (string[i] >= 97 && string[i] <= 122) || string[i] == 10) {
    sec_str[j] = tolower(string[i]);
    putchar(sec_str[j]);
    j++;
}
}
printf("%s\n", sec_str);
```

This is my code, was trying to copy one string to another one, stripping all non letter cases, and that works fine for me, I use putchar(sec_str[j]) to check and they are all good, but when I check with the printf("%s", sec_str), the output was a mess. something like this:

```
asantaspotstopsatnasa
asantaspotstopsatnasa

twasbrilligandtheslithytoves
twasbrilligandtheslithytoves
����r�$
yobananaboy
yobananaboy
ndth
neveroddoreven
neveroddoreven
h
thetimehascomethewalrussaid
thetimehascomethewalrussaid
����t�r�$
```

and the printf should print

```
asantaspotstopsatnasa
twasbrilligandtheslithytoves
yobananaboy
neveroddoreven
thetimehascomethewalrussaid
```

to be correctly

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add a null terminator to the end of the string :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
...
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if(ischar(string[i]) ||  (string[i] == 10) ) {
      sec_str[j] = tolower(string[i]);
      putchar(sec_str[j]);
      j++;
    }
  }
  sec_string[j] = '\0';
  printf("%s\n", sec_str);
```